# MPI velocity sending

Tags: mpi

I have a simple question, but it requires a depp knowledge of computer architecture.
I'm using MPI, all processors need to read some data from the same text file. It is quicker to let each processor accedes to the txt file or is better to read the file with a single processor and then send the data to the other?

Comment: The latter is better in almost all cases. If your I/O subsystem and code are good then it might turn out to be about the same. If your "some" data means a significant amount then it might be worthwhile to have each processor load a piece and then do an All-to-All. Parsing is very CPU intensive.

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell - it will depend on the size of the file, the number of nodes, the relative bandwidth and latency of your MPI fabric versus that of your SAN, your OS's caching policy and volume of RAM and any number of other things.